# Linux Mint not opening when after typing password, goes back to login screen again like a loophole.(EXT4) (More details in desc.)

Tags: linux-mint, login

Title. Before I closed Linux Mint, a notification came saying like: No free space in Filesystem root.(I have /home and root in the same partition) I was surprised and then ran Bleachbit as root and cleared only trash and other files that are quick to clean and those I wasn't afraid it will ruin the OS. Also ran Stacer, cleared out basically everything it can, but then there was still 0 bytes of free space left. I had to go somewhere so then shut it down. Then I was on the login page, then typed my password(It's probably not a password problem because I have basically muscle-memorized the password.), it went to a black screen with a cursor (probably legacy or underline) and went back to then login screen. I was using Cinnamon DE so then I tried out Ubuntu DE and Xfce, but the same thing happened. Then I went in Recovery mode, then i clicked the option for clean drive. Thought it was going to like tell me which packages or files to keep, but just ran "apt autoremove" and I had no files to clean. Sorry if I don't provide enough info, I just don't really know what else to type. I also think that maybe Linux Mint thinks its creating logs in Login, but it can't, and when it checks it doesn't think I'm logging in so it just keeps looping back.
Thanks, nullroot.

Answers to questions:

1: No I don't think I can do that, but I'll try.

2: I don't think this is a Hard Drive failure because I'm using an SSD, and it's in Dual Boot with Windows 10. The SSD was bought couple months ago, so there really can't be any Old Drive failures. I know SSDs also have failures but then they're not the same as HDD failures. I also thought of booting into a live distro of Ubuntu or something like that and then delete some files in the root partition and then boot back into Mint and try to login.

I did system check option and this is what it said about my partition where Mint is installed:

```
 (name or something like that)   Total space    Used space     Avail    Used%

      /dev/sda4                    147G            142G         0b      100%
```

So i think that Mint is thinking that the partition is full, or the partition is corrupted, so I'm gonna wipe the disk and start fresh. I actually don't have anything precious.

Comment: Are you able to get a command line terminal with root access in recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe may be indicative of a failing hard disk, especially where you say you have cleared out unwanted files and it is still showing 0 free space. I have experienced that login loop error in the past myself and it can happen if there is not enough free space in your `/home` directory (or its partition is not mounted as writable).

I recommend backing up your critical data asap and you might want to look at running some hard disk diagnostics and/or get a new one.